Reduce date in database by 5 minutes
In my anylogic model I have a database which, among other things, has a column with times in date format:
2023-07-16 04:10:00.0
2023-07-16 04:14:00.0
2023-07-16 04:14:00.0
2023-07-16 04:15:00.0
2023-07-16 04:17:00.0

I'm trying to subtract 5 min from each cell in that column and save this time in a new column.
Does anyone has a solution for this problem.
Many thanks for your help.

Assuming your table is called db_table, the first date date1 and the second date date_minus_5, this is what you can do:
List <Date> x=selectFrom(db_table)
    .list(db_table.date1);
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
for(Date t : x){
    cal.setTime(t);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
    
    update(db_table).where(db_table.date1.eq(t))
        .set(db_table.date_minus_5, cal.getTime())
        .execute();
}


Or avoiding the cumbersome and outdated Calendar class, define Instant minus5 = t.toInstant.minus(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES); and then set b_table.date_minus_5 to Date.from(minus5).

Thanks for your help, it works now. Is there a way that I can create a new column in my data base by code, so if  the column "data_minus_5 is not existing?

@KevinEtter you shouldn't change the database structure on runtime... that is a biiiiiiiiiiig mistake... whatever you are trying to do, do it in a way where you don't need to change the database structure

Assuming you have the new column already:

Loop through all the entries. You can use the dbase wizard if you do not know the Java syntax
read the Date, convert to java.util.LocalDateTime
Subtract 5 mins using LocalDateTime functions (minus(...))
convert back to Date
write into the new column using INSERT INTO SQL statement


Your JDBC driver or JPA implementation can directly handle LocalDateTime. No need to convert to or from Date in Java. See this answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash. Assuming the OP wants the calculated time into the same database row, use update (not insert).

thx @Anonymous but this is a special DB inside of AnyLogic, not the usual setup. No classic jdbc bridge stuff, etc.

Kevin, only use the "anylogic" tag, else Java coders get confused as above ;)

I don’t think that what confused me was myself adding datetime and other tags I considered relevant. True, though, i didn’t consider the question a Java question but commented on this answer as a Java answer.

Are you saying that using the database inside AnyLogic requires you to use a Date class that has severe design problems and has (otherwise) been outdated for 10 years? Thanks for the warning. I will avoid AnyLogic for some time to come.
